# Unwanted search results while running overloaded PLSQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am creating an overloaded PLSQL stored procedure which allows to display the names of schools, their corresponding category (elementary, etc), and neighbourhood they belong to.

The names of schools is taken from table `OTTAWASCHOOLS` from the field `NAME`. The category is taken from the table `OTTAWASCHOOLS` from the field `CATEGORY`.

In addition, the user has the choice to input a particular neighbourhood to find the above information of the schools in that neighbourhood. The name of the neighbourhood is taken from the `OTTAWANEIGHBOUR` table from the field `NAME`.

However, if the user does NOT input a specific neighbourhood, the output will display the names ALL the schools in the `OTTAWASCHOOLS` table with their respective neighbourhoods and categories

(I have created only one procedure at the moment).

My code is as follows

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE schools_package 
AS

PROCEDURE find_school
(neighbourhood_name     IN  OTTAWANEIGHBOUR.NAME%TYPE);
END schools_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY schools_package
AS
PROCEDURE find_school
(neighbourhood_name     IN  OTTAWANEIGHBOUR.NAME%TYPE)
IS

school_category             OTTAWASCHOOLS.CATEGORY%TYPE;
school_name                 OTTAWASCHOOLS.NAME%TYPE;
v_neighbourhood_name        OTTAWANEIGHBOUR.NAME%TYPE;

CURSOR c_schools IS
SELECT NAME, CATEGORY
FROM eluliGDM.OTTAWASCHOOLS;

r_schools c_schools%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NEIGHBOURHOOD  ' || 'CATEGORY  '|| 'SCHOOL NAME  ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('-------------  ' || '--------  '|| '-----------  ');

FOR r_schools IN c_schools
    LOOP
    SELECT c1.NAME, c2.NAME, c2.CATEGORY
    INTO v_neighbourhood_name, school_name, school_category
    FROM eluliGDM.OTTAWANEIGHBOUR c1, eluliGDM.OTTAWASCHOOLS c2
    WHERE  SDO_RELATE (c2.GEOMETRY, c1.GEOMETRY, 'MASK=INSIDE+COVEREDBY QUERYTYPE=JOIN') = 'TRUE'
    AND c2.NAME=r_schools.NAME;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_neighbourhood_name || school_category|| school_name);
END LOOP;
END find_school;
END schools_package;

-----------TESTING STORED PROCEDURE---------------
Execute schools_package.find_school();
Execute schools_package.find_school('Mer Bleue');
```

However, the results show ALL the neighbourhoods and their corresponding schools (even though I specified a neighbourhood when I tested the procedure)

Answer (score 1):

The Where clause is missing in the cursor. Since there is no where clause, all neighbourhoods will be returned in the cursor, even if you pass the neighbourhood name in the procedure.

```
CURSOR c_schools IS
SELECT NAME, CATEGORY
FROM eluliGDM.OTTAWASCHOOLS;
--> WHERE name = neighbourhood_name
```